# I need time from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
AS

SELECT     TOP 50 *
FROM         dbo.Ritten

WHERE     (Status = 0)and (Afgemeld = 0)

ORDER BY CAST(Datum AS date),Tijd
```

Output = 13:30:00.0000000

I need this = 13:30

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say, the output is `13:30:00.0000000`, but your SELECT statement is supposed to return `TOP 50 *`, which means more than one row (very likely) *and* more than one column (*most* likely). So it would be much more helpful if you showed the output in the form of a table, *then* pointed out what particular part of the output you were having issues with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST(Datum as DateTime),108) ...
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/06/sql-server-get-time-in-hourminute-format-from-a-datetime-get-date-part-only-from-datetime/

Comment: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07' 

Error converting data type date to varchar. 

Not working :(

Comment: Can you try this instead: SELECT CONVERT(TIME,CAST(Dateum as Date)) to see if it works and then we strip the seconds?

Comment: Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_Laatste5Orders, Line 8
Explicit conversion from data type date to time is not allowed.

Comment: Oh, i see the problem. CAST dateum as DATETIME not DATE.

Comment: Great. Now we can use the SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST(Datum as DateTime),108). I updated the original answer so it contains the corect CAST to DateTime instead.

Comment: Same output from: ORDER BY CAST(Datum AS date),CONVERT(TIME,CAST(Datum as Datetime)),CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CAST(Datum as DateTime),108)

Comment: Tijd is the tabel ! it contains time(7)

Comment: We could use the function LEFT(<date expression>, 5) to make sure it displays only the first 5 chars http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx

Comment: If `Tijd` is the table, why is it in your `ORDER BY` clause and your `FROM` is actually `dbo.Ritten`?

Comment: @user1203655: Did you mean to say, *‘Tijd is a **column** ’* ?

Comment: @user1203655 `104` returns 12-hour format. It should be `114`. Try my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), Datum, 8)
  FROM Tijd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Seconds` value right?

```
SELECT convert(varchar(15), getdate(), 114) 
-- (will return HH:mm:ss:mmm format [24 hr])
```

so in your query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(15), CAST(Datum as DateTime), 114),1,5) as DateString
-- this will return HH:mm format
```

[T-SQL Date Format](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: Strongly recommend against `convert(varchar` without a length (see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).